# Invisible roof in XCOM: Enemy Within on iOS

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I am trying to move a soldier up a ladder to the roof in the iOS version of XCOM: Enemy Within. I used the camera tool to raise my elevation, but the rooftop is invisible, and the roof area is unselectable for movement.

[image: Unclimbable ladder and invisible roof]

How do I make the roof visible so I can climb the ladder?

Comment: Think in the PC version if you zoomed out it showed the roof. That or moving to the base of the ladder, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the first non-tutorial stage just has bugged ladders on the iOS version. I was able to climb ladders and pipes on every stage but this one by switching layers (two finger swipe) to the roof.

Even after starting a new file, this was the only stage where I could not access the roof.